# Swiper with non-sibling slides

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am using swiper as a slider for my mobile view. Basically, the divs that I would like to apply `swiper-slide` class are not siblings of each other.

Here's the sample fiddle to demonstrate my use-case: https://jsfiddle.net/2prcosmk/

Whenever I try to use swiper that way, the first slide is shown correctly but I can not perform actual sliding from first to any other slides (as its obvious in the demo fiddle when you try to move the slider). I wonder if its possible. I can not really re-organize my html as I have multiple cards in multiple columns so each of these card would become one slide and so would the entire header.

Can you provide some suggestion here or any pointer on the code sample I've put? Thanks!

Update: I tried nesting the swiper-* classes in https://jsfiddle.net/2prcosmk/2/ and it does create swipers but the nested swiper content are just not displayed. If I make inner swiper `direction: 'horizontal'`, it creates vertical swiper inside horizontal swiper as expected but `horizontal` inside `horizontal` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest I could go was to use `nested: true` and `direction: 'horizontal'` in the inner swiper. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2prcosmk/3/ . One problem probably would be the pagination setup so if anyone can answer how we can combine together the two paginations, that would be awesome but for now, this is good enough.